# RBAC passes in an IFrame to be read in an API call?

Tags: asp.net-core, security, azure-active-directory, plotly-dash

I have my ASP.NET Core front-end web application that authenticates the users against the `Azure Active Directory` and only if the user is authenticated, it can see the website. And this part is working.

There is ASP.NET Core project for the APIs and, again, the authentication is required always against Azure Active Directory. If the call is coming from the application above with an authenticated user, the request can go through.

There are some databases hosted in a virtual machine in Azure. The APIs have access to them.

Now, in this scenario, There is another application created with [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/). The client wants to host this application in page that requires authentication in an `iframe` in the ASP.NET Core web. So, only if a user has the authorization can access this page.

The application in Dash has to call a database (in the VM) or the APIs (the ASP.NET Core project) and both of them require the authentication again Azure Active Directory.

All those applications can use the same base URLs (like appname.myserver.com).

Summarize:

- user authentication in the front-end
- page with authentication hosted an iframe
- the Dash application calls the database
- ?
- the Dash application calls the APIs
- ?

I'm not sure if the authentication and authorization from the front-end application can be passed into the iframe and from here to the database or the APIs.

The 2 question marks in the above summary are to understand if the database and the APIs can receive the user token or not.